# How to stop auto opening of apps?

Tags: login

I built and ran a graphics program that triggers a driver bug that hard freezes my M1 Max computer.

Running Monterey 12.2.1.

When it comes back, upon login, Xcode opens and immediately runs the offending program. There is no time available to interrupt Xcode. The computer is too fast :(. I'd like to know if there is something I can press on the keyboard to force login to stop "helpfully" reopening everything for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying SSH and realizing it does not accept my password for some reason, I went ahead and tried the simplest thing I could think of and it worked.

Just hold shift while hitting enter when logging in.

Comment: Indeed! https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-items-automatically-when-you-log-in-mh15189/11.0/mac/11.0